Antichrist as the mahdi
Can anyone confirm wether this hadith is sahih or not, if so wouldn't it be very similar to the 7 year covenant of the antichrist with the Jews that's mentioned in Daniel 9:27
"4.5 Al- Mahdi’s Treaty With Romans According to various Islamic theological sources, al-Mahdi is said to be one who will initiate Islam’s fourth and final treaty between the “Romans” and the Muslims. Al-Mahdi will make this treaty for a period of seven years! In a Hadith, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said: “There will be four peace agreements between you and the Romans. The fourth will be mediated through a person who will be from the progeny of Hazrat Aaron (the brother of Moses) and will be upheld for seven years. The people asked, “O Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), who will be the Imam (leader) of the people at that time?” The Prophet said: “He will be from my progeny and will be exactly forty years of age. His face will shine like a star” (Tabarani, as related by Hadrat Abu Umamah, as quoted by Zubair Ali,2004, p. 43).It appears that the period of this seven year peace agreement will likewise be the period of the Mahdi’s reign."

Hi Tahir, I believe you've been trying to ask questions here that are best on the Islam stack exchange. It is not really possible from our side to say if something about the nature of Islam is related to a specific passage of the Bible.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Christianity.

Instead of uselessly closing this, can we migrate it to islam.stackexchange, it asks for an islamic interpretation?
@Tahir you should post questions like this on the islam stack exchange.

Valid QuestionModern Christian interpreters of Daniel often use this scripture as a jumping off place to introduce the ominous figure antichrist. This opens the question of whether the Christian scriptures are speaking of the same person in Islam. Migrating this OP to Islam would merely cause that site to wonder if this should be migrated to Christianity S.E. since it asks about the person in Daniel, the Christian literature!

Presupposition This important question assumes that there is mention of an Anti-christ in Daniel 9:27. And it presumes an interpretation of a 7 year period of peace (or 7 year covenant). And that this is a correct interpretation often given by Christians.
So it is first necessary to see if there is any such teaching in Daniel 9, which is worthy of comparison with Islamic scripture. If there is none, then the hadith teaching stands on its own, and any attempt at comparison is meaningless.

Know therefore and understand that from the going forth of the commandment to restore and to build Jerusalem unto the Messiah the Prince (the Anointed One, the Prince) shall be seven heptads, and threescore and two heptads...and after the threescore and two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, but not for Himself...And He shall confirm the covenant with many for one heptad (seven years) and in the midst of the heptad (3 1/2 years) He shall cause the sacrifice and oblation to cease...(Daniel 9:25-27)

The context of any scripture is so important. And so here in Daniel (a) it is seen that there is absolutely no mention of any Antichrist (no anti-anointed person)...only an "anointed" person!
(b)And that this Anointed person is to arrive on the historical scene 490 years after the Return of the Jews from the diaspora exile. This places the Anointed One's appearance in the First Century of the Christian Era.
(c) And this Anointed One is to be "cut off" (killed). [Again, no mention of an anti-christ.]
(d) That the final heptad (7 years) is to be marked by a causing of the Sacrifice to be ceased in the midst of it, and that it would see the Covenant be confirmed (established).
No Anti-ChristContrary to some modern popular interpretations in Christianity, there is no mention of an anti-christ making a covenant with the Jews for seven years anywhere in this scripture of Daniel! It just isn't any there.
Therefore the person mentioned in the Islamic scripture is someone totally different than the alleged "anti-christ" figure.  Whomever the Hadith describes, it is not an anti-christ of the Bible. There is no anti-christ of the Bible described in Daniel. So the Islamic prophecy stands alone.
Therefore, there can be no meaningful comparison.
AddendumNote that while the Islam scripture mentioned "7 years of peace", those modern Christian commentators who see an anti-christ in Daniel, also teach that there will only be 3 1/2 years of peace, and then betrayal of antichrist, and then 3 1/2 years of tribulation. So Islam and Jewish scripture is different.
Tahir, thank you for investigating and considering the Holy Scriptures of Christendom. May your research find you rest in the salvation of God. Peace.

+1 for the clear but gracious and conciliatory tone of your answer. Well done.
